# Filter using Range-Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

Following is the kibana JSON of a single row,

```
{
  "_index": "questionanswers",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "3",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "question": {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "Your first salary",
      "answer_type": "FL",
      "question_type": "BQ"
    },
    "candidate": {
      "id": 13
    },
    "job": {
      "id": 6
    },
    "id": 3,
    "status": "AN",
    "answered_on": "2019-07-12T09:26:01+00:00",
    "answer": "12222222"
  },
  "fields": {
    "answered_on": [
      "2019-07-12T09:26:01.000Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have an sql query like,

```
Select * from questionanswers where question.id = 3 and answer between 1250 and 1253666
```

I have converted this to elasticsearch query as follows,

```
{
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "question.id":3
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "answer": {
                            "from": 1250,
                            "to": 1253666999,
                            "include_lower": true,
                            "include_upper": true,
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Here `answer` is declared as String , But i holds Date,FLoat and String values.

```
 "question": {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "Your first salary",
      "answer_type": "FL",
      "question_type": "BQ"
    },
```

Here `answer_type` tells which type of answer it is expecting.

When I try to run this query I am not getting desired results. I am getting an empty response on this hit.
But actually, there is a row that satisfies this query.
How my elasticsearch query should be so that I can filter with

````
question.id = 3 , question.answer_type = "FL" and answer between 1250 and 1253666```
````

Answer (score 0):

see your document again. The `answer` is a string value, and you are treating as a `number` in your query. So it does not work obviously.

change the `mapping` for this field to number.

Here is the document I indexed in a test index and ran your query again and it works

**Indexing the document** ( see the field `answer`)

```
POST /so-index4/_doc/1
{
   "question": {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "Your first salary",
      "answer_type": "FL",
      "question_type": "BQ"
    },
    "candidate": {
      "id": 13
    },
    "job": {
      "id": 6
    },
    "id": 3,
    "status": "AN",
    "answered_on": "2019-07-12T09:26:01+00:00",
    "answer": 12222222,
  "fields": {
    "answered_on": [
      "2019-07-12T09:26:01.000Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

**and the query** (same query that you provided above)

```
GET /so-index4/_search
{
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "question.id":3
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "answer": {
                            "from": 1250,
                            "to": 1253666999,
                            "include_lower": true,
                            "include_upper": true,
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    }
}
```

**the result**

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 2.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "so-index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "question" : {
            "id" : 3,
            "text" : "Your first salary",
            "answer_type" : "FL",
            "question_type" : "BQ"
          },
          "candidate" : {
            "id" : 13
          },
          "job" : {
            "id" : 6
          },
          "id" : 3,
          "status" : "AN",
          "answered_on" : "2019-07-12T09:26:01+00:00",
          "answer" : 12222222,
          "fields" : {
            "answered_on" : [
              "2019-07-12T09:26:01.000Z"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: answer is just a variable that is declared in String, But it holds Date, String,Float data types
You might have noticed there is a field "answer_type" which tells what type of answer it is expecting

Comment: with this ` "answer": "12222222"` you can't query with a `number` unless there is some sort of analyzer or some other way

Comment: I have modified the question for better understanding,
Bascially i am looking for filter conditions,
 question.id = 3 , question.answer_type = "FL" and answer between 1250 and 1253666